# Access Denied in Bin Folder for ASP.NET Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, windows-server-2003

Using Visual Studio 2008, I have published my ASP.NET website to my local disk in preparation for deploying to our test server. Using an RDP session, I've connected to the test server running Windows Server 2003, making my local disk available as a resource to the RDP session. When I attempt to copy the files from my local disk to the server, everything copies without issue *except* for the DLLs in the bin folder. Every time I try to copy a DLL I get the following error: "Cannot copy [filename]: Access is denied. Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected and that the file is not currently in use." I am able to copy any file outside the bin folder and any file except DLLs in the bin folder (such as .compiled files).

It's been a while since I've worked with IIS and ASP.NET so I'm admittedly a little rusty but I've tried everything I know of to fix the issue. I checked the obvious, there's 3+ GB free on the disk, and the file is not write-protected.

I've also tried everything I can think of to make sure the files are not in use. I tried recycling the application pool, restarting the default web site, both restarting IIS and stopping/starting IIS using the GUI, ending the w3wp.exe process in task manager, Shift-deleting the file, deleting from the command prompt, having two other users attempt to delete the files using their login credentials, and restarting the server twice. Nothing at all has worked so far and I'm at my wit's end.

Hoping someone has any suggestions on what else I can try to fix this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you copy the files elsewhere or can you copy any other file to the destination bin folder?

Comment: I'd stop IIS, close Visual Studio, right click on folder -> properties - > security and ensure that your user has full permissions.  Then I'd try and copy

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu Yes, I can copy the files to another location on the server. I can also copy other files to the destination bin folder. Everything I've tried works no problem, just not the DLLs.

Comment: @RobA I think I've tried what you suggested. I stopped IIS, and tried to copy (it failed) before starting IIS back up. I am an administrator on the server and have full control that way, but I've also made sure that my user has full permission to the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try stopping IIS from the command prompt, then restart and after restarting confirming that IIS is still stopped.

After confirmation of the above, zip the files, copy the zipped file over to your server and unzip. Run AV on the files, and you may need to "unlock" the zip.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Via the command prompt, I stopped IIS, restarted it, and stopped it again, confirming that w3wp.exe was not present in the Task Manager when I didn't expect it to be. When I tried to unzip the files to the bin folder, I was met with the same issue as when I attempt to copy directly: everything else copies fine but the DLLs all give me "access is denied" errors.

Comment: What AV are you running on the server? 

Try running filemon on the directory in which those files reside to see what is locking them.

Comment: Just wanted to post the resolution to the problem. Turns out there's an application running on the server that prevents changes to files but I couldn't tell it was any different than a problem with Windows permissions. I don't think it's exactly anti-virus software but that did get me pointed in the right direction, thanks for your help!